# В чем отличие Context.getString() от Resources.getString()?

Tags: android-sdk, android

В чем отличие Context.getString() от Resources.getString()?
Когда вызываешь getResources().getString(R.string.someString);
Как я понял и протестировал результат один и тот же.
В чем отличие?
Или это просто дублирование?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дублирование. Код `Context.getString`:

```
public final String getString(int resId)
{
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```